# Can you get MethodInfo from a static method of a static class without a magic string?

Tags: .net, reflection, lambda, expression

Let's say I have this static class with a static method:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    public static void MyMethod() { }
}
```

I could get the `MethodInfo` like this:

`MethodInfo MethodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod");`

However, if I ever change the name of the method, the magical properties of the string will cause the method name to remain unchanged.  If it were a non-static class/method, I could do this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod() { }
}
```

`MethodInfo MethodInfo = new Action<MyClass>(x => x.MyMethod()).Method;`

This is great because it's a reference to the method signature itself, so I can change the original method name and then rename all references.  However, this method doesn't work with the static version of my class/method.

Is there a way to use the lambda with a static class?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using. VS2015 (C# 6) has a new feature just for situations like this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain 2013/4.5.1.  If I have to use a magic string until we upgrade, I guess I'll have to.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with C# 6.0 you can use [`nameof` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dn986596.aspx) for this:

```
MethodInfo MethodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod(nameof(MyClass.MyMethod));
```

Comment: That's really nice.  We'll be upgrading to 2015 soon enough, so I'll have to find a way to do it with 4.5.1 or use a magic string.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin Another thing to note is that you do not need to upgrade to .NET 4.6 in order to use `nameof`. It works with 4.5.2, because it's a compiler trick.